# PL/SQL Procedure error ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and I am trying to make a procedure with 2 cursors and I have no ideea why am I having this error:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

```
PROCEDURE filme_pret IS
CURSOR planificari_pret_redus (pret_propus NUMBER) IS   
SELECT * FROM planificare WHERE pret < pret_propus ;
obiect planificari_pret_redus%rowtype;
CURSOR planificari_pret_normal IS  
SELECT * FROM planificare;
obiect2 planificari_pret_normal%rowtype;
    BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Filme cu pret redus');
    for obiect in planificari_pret_redus(100) 
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(obiect.idplanificare || ' ' || obiect.idfilm  || ' ' || obiect.pret);
    END LOOP;
for obiect2 in planificari_pret_normal
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(obiect2.idplanificare || ' ' || obiect2.idfilm  || ' ' || obiect2.pret);
    END LOOP;

    END;
```

Thank you.

Comment: The second loop is using `obiect` rather than `obiect2`.

Comment: `planificari_pret_normal` cursor doesn't allow parameters

Comment: thank you, i have updated and i still have this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main part of your code is ok, you simply have to decide how to use it; if you want to create a procedure without storing it, you need a complete `DECLARE...BEGIN...END` block:

```
DECLARE
    /* declare your procedure */
    PROCEDURE filme_pret IS
        CURSOR planificari_pret_redus(pret_propus NUMBER) IS
            SELECT *
              FROM planificare
             WHERE pret < pret_propus;

        obiect     planificari_pret_redus%ROWTYPE;

        CURSOR planificari_pret_normal  IS
            SELECT * FROM planificare;

        obiect2    planificari_pret_normal%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Filme cu pret redus');

        FOR obiect IN planificari_pret_redus(100) LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(obiect.idplanificare || ' ' || obiect.idfilm || ' ' || obiect.pret);
        END LOOP;

        FOR obiect2 IN planificari_pret_normal LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(obiect2.idplanificare || ' ' || obiect2.idfilm || ' ' || obiect2.pret);
        END LOOP;
    END;
BEGIN
    /* CALL YOU PROCEDURE */        
    filme_pret;
END;
/
```

This way your procedure is not stored in DB, and you always need to use the entire block; if you want to create a stored procedure, you need this syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE filme_pret IS
    CURSOR planificari_pret_redus(pret_propus NUMBER) IS
        SELECT *
          FROM planificare
         WHERE pret < pret_propus;

    obiect     planificari_pret_redus%ROWTYPE;

    CURSOR planificari_pret_normal  IS
        SELECT * FROM planificare;

    obiect2    planificari_pret_normal%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Filme cu pret redus');

    FOR obiect IN planificari_pret_redus(100) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(obiect.idplanificare || ' ' || obiect.idfilm || ' ' || obiect.pret);
    END LOOP;

    FOR obiect2 IN planificari_pret_normal LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(obiect2.idplanificare || ' ' || obiect2.idfilm || ' ' || obiect2.pret);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

After this, you can simply call your procedure in a PL/SQL block:

```
begin
    filme_pret;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

is that a typo ?

```
obiect planificari%rowtype;
```

it seems that `planificari` doesn't exists.

Comment: thank you, that was wrong. but i still have the same error

Comment: I don't see any other error a part from the fact you should use CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE.... if it is a standalone procedure , i mean, that is not included in a package. Also check the field names you are using , since i can't know if they are right or not.

Comment: ah and i also forget to say that if you are in SQL*PLUS you should end your procedure with a slash.